# Plastic scm global client.conf not working

Tags: plasticscm

I'm trying to set proxy server in client.conf globally. But it does not working.

I created *plastic-global-config repo* on cloud, created "allrepo" folder, added client.conf file in it, committed. But after restarting GUIclient, globalconfig folder doesn't appeared in `/local/plastic4` folder.

My client.conf file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClientConfigData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Language>en</Language>
  <WorkingMode>LDAPWorkingMode</WorkingMode>
  <CacheServer>192.168.1.231:9999</CacheServer>
</ClientConfigData>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the "client.conf" is a local client file that cannot be globally configured. Please check the following link where we explain all the available files to be globally configured:

https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide